# How to detect country information through browser using ava

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, gwt, servlets

I have a requirement that I should show the date in particular country's format in my GWT-DateBox. I have a experience that can get locale from request, It gives the information about what browser has the language. If user change the browser's language, then my requirement will get satisfy. But this is bad case, I feel. I need a particular country information without changing the browser's language. I hope my problem will understand. Please help me out from this issue.

More Info about application: GWT, GoogleAppEngine, Java.

Example: My browser language is en_US by default, means, using this I can format the date in USA. If I want the format for India, I should not change my browser language, without change the browser's language, I need date format of browser locale.

Any reply would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use MaxMind APIs to find which city IP is coming from based on that you can tell what language   or date format you need to display here is the [link](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite) for you.
code example:

```
   LookupService cl = new LookupService(dbfile,LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

   System.out.println(cl.getCountry("151.38.39.114").getCode());
```

[more detail](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-java/blob/master/CountryLookupTest.java)

Comment: Hi CPU 100, thanks for your time. As I know that it is some cost oriented. I knew about it. I am searching for some open source API, please let me know, If you can.

Comment: This is free if you use it for your personal project. There is a commercial version too but for the free version you can use this link http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable (please feel free to give me 1+ on my answer)

Comment: How can I use the API for sample one, Please let me to test this sample java project. So please tell me the steps. I am unable to voting you. Sorry ..

Comment: Just now I joined in this blog, I should have more than 15 score to do vote your comment. Now I have 11 itself. Please Increase for me, then I can help you.